# PostgreSQL GROUP BY calculating percentile

Tags: postgresql, loops, group-by, aggregate-functions

i have an table t1 with an 250x250m grid with population and i want to calculate the percentile for each state. i already have the state_id for each cell (st_contains).
now i want to calculate the percentile for each state.

solution, add PARTITION ;)

```
   SELECT  *,
   ntile(100) OVER(PARTITION BY state_id ORDER BY pop) as percentile
   FROM t1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without table definition and some sample data and expected output it is hard to dream up what the best solution would be, but this will *probably* do it:

```
WITH x AS
  (
   SELECT  *,
   ntile(100) OVER (PARTITION BY state_id ORDER BY pop) as percentile
   FROM t1
  )
UPDATE t1
SET state_percentile = percentile
FROM x
WHERE t1.id = x.id;
```

Comment: this calculates the percentile over all states, but i want to calculate it for each state.